# How to get the current cmd line of (neo)vim?

Tags: external-command

If I start with nvim -u NONE , I want to get "-u NONE".

I tried to get pid using bash and python, but it seems to return the pid of the process that is created (either python or bash).

So how should I do it?

Comment: It might be in argv or something similar. These are the command arguments, not the current command line of (n)vim.

Comment: These are the files in the argument list. Not what I need.

Comment: Just to give context, I want to load the default workspace only if neovim started with no arguments. `echo "xxx" | nvim - ` consist of an argument, and loading the default workspace ruins this option.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going the Python + `ps` route, then this should be better and more efficient:

```
:pyx import os, subprocess
:let vim_cmdline = pyxeval("subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-p', str(os.getpid()), '-o', 'cmd='])")
```

Note that you're checking for the current PID (`os.getpid()`), since the Python interpreter is running *inside* the current Vim process.

One (definitely Linux-only!) method that doesn't involve Python *or* `ps` is to read from the `/proc` filesystem directly. It turns out `/proc/self` has information about the current process, and the `cmdline` file has the command line (separated with NUL bytes.)

You can get the current command-line in a Vim list with:

```
let vim_cmdline = split(readfile('/proc/self/cmdline')[0], '\n', 1)
```

It's not 100% perfect. If you have arguments with a newline in them, then this expression wil discard them (they'd be indices `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. in the list), but it's probably good enough for most purposes, since arguments with newlines are typically quite rare.

---

**UPDATE**: This does a better job at it, taking into account newline characters, etc.:

```
function! VimCmdLine()
  let c = map(readfile('/proc/self/cmdline'), {_, v -> split(v, '\n', 1)})
  let r = c[0]
  for i in c[1:]
    let r[-1] = r[-1]."\n".i[0]
    let r = r + i[1:]
  endfor
  return r[:-2]
endfunction
```

Also returns a list, with one element per command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is what I came up with.

Find the current process, the process parent, and use `ps ax` to obtain the path. Meant to work in mac. in Linux, it is easier with `/proc/XXX/cmdline'.

```
PY import vim
PY import os
PY pid=os.getpid()
PY kk=os.popen('ps -o ppid= -p ' + str(pid)).read()
PY kk=kk.replace('\n','')
PY tt=("let cmdline=system('ps ax | grep \""+kk + "\" | grep nvim | grep -v grep | /usr/bin/sed \"s/^.*\///\"')")
PY vim.command(tt)
```